# How to find all previously installed apps deleted from history?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, history

I'm looking for a game I played in the past that I'm willing to pay for today. I usually delete my history when you go to the **Play Store - My Apps - All**. That means all I have there are the currently installed apps on my phone.

However, I found these little marks on previously installed apps that aren't currently on my phone but have been deleted from my history.

[image: check mark symbols]

Is there a way to find all apps with these check marks on them?

Comment: The check mark indicates that it's currently installed on one of your device. Do you have other Android phones/tablets which are logged in with your account?

Comment: Hi Andrew! None of those apps are installed on my device. These are old apps that have been uninstalled and have been deleted from my app history. I only have 1 registered to my account. I found the game but this would be some nice info for other people who might need to know how to do it as well.

Comment: Do you see all your apps under https://play.google.com/apps ? It shows all the apps that you previously installed on your phone.